# hidebottombarwhenpush is not working in moving tabbarcontroller storyboard to another storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, pushviewcontroller

Here is my question like I am having a storyboard called `Tabbar.storyboard` and another storyboard called `Main.storyboard`. `Tabbar.storyboard` is my initial storyboard and application starts with that storyboard. Now when I move from `Tabbar` storyboard to `Main` storyboard with enabled **`hidebottombarwhenpushed`**, `Tabbar` hides successfully but left an empty view instead.

I also put **`hidebottombarwhenpushed`** in my viewcontroller in which I pushed from tabbar controller but nothing worked

here is my [image] of Tabbar storyboard.

Here is my [image: TabbarVC] in simulator.

Here when I push from Tabbar storyboard to main storyboard Tabbar is hidden but left an empty view. [image] of simulator where you see an empty view at bottom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just add one navigation controller before your tab bar controller your problem slove

Answer (score 0):

If you are using constraints, check if the bottom constraint of your UICollectionView [?] in your UIViewController are being set to "bottomLayoutGuide" (also check if "use safe area" option is checked/unchecked).

Using the XCode's view debugger is also helpful. Try to see where are the bounds of your views, and check if some constraints aren't being broken.

Comment: I am not using any constraint and also safe area option is checked. Problem is occue when moving from tabbar controller to another storyboard vc

Comment: Those are webviews, right? I didn't saw the storyboard on the link before... Just the screenshots, sorry.

Comment: No these are not webviews, It is a viewcontroller of another storboard